# WooCommerce OrderBy Price Not working... Very Strange

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

if you go here:  http://www.kineticskateboarding.com/product-category/footwear/?orderby=price

You will see that the prices do not get ordered.  I don't understand where to look for this specific issue, as it only happens with the prices (High to Low) and (Low to High).  There are 2 different types of products, Variable Products and Simple Products, how does Woocommerce grab the price for sorting it in this way?  From each variation?  Where to look for fixing this myself even?

Thanks all.

Comment: It looks like every sorting option (except by brand) is showing the same order of items.

Comment: That's definitely not what it looks like to me.  Popularity sorts it completely different.  Also, this is a baby site, so there are, very little, to no ratings, and others might not even show much.

Comment: Apparently I didn't look at the popularity option, but the default sort, Low -> High, and High -> Low are showing the same order

Comment: The code for sorting is under woocommerce > templates > loop > orderby.php may be you can tweak a bit in there or copy to your template if you have your own.. and this is the filter "woocommerce_catalog_orderby" that does all the sorting

Comment: That file does not do the actual sorting, that is the template.  The file that does the actual sorting is the `class-wc-query.php` file.  And according to that file, it is using the meta_key of `_price` to sort by, but the problem is, that it is not working!

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason you are having an issue is poor Documentation from WooCommerce.

In order to sort by price you need to set

`orderBy='meta_value_num'` NOT `orderBy='meta_value'` as stated in their docs.

I believe `meta_value` treats them as strings so as `AAAA` comes before `BB` `$111.10` comes before `$2.00`

I came across this answer by submitting an issue with WooCommerce https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/10182

Answer (score 0):

Check your product variations. WooCommerce sorts it according to the default attribute price. Also verify if you have other plugins that affect product sorting/pricing.

Comment: the `_price` post meta key exists for all products if that is what you are talking about.  I would hope that it would use `_price` meta_value for the product, and not the variations, since the product is where the price is.

Comment: Is that what it uses?  The `_price` meta_value within the `postmeta` table for the actual id of the product?  Where `post_id` = the product id, not the variations id, right?  If that is the case, than it is sorting it wrong.  I can verify this by looking at the `meta_value` column for the `_price` meta_key of these products.